# call a method in class, inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, methods, call, point

I have a problem, the solution is probably very easy, but nothing comes to mind at the moment, so I am looking for a little help.

... so I have a problem with calling the method.

I have a Space 2D class:

```
    public class Space2D {
    
    //several other methods etc.
    
    //for example I will take this method

    public double distance(Space2D p1, Space2D p2) {
            double dx = p1.x - p2.x;
            double dy = p1.y - p2.y;
            return Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
        }
    }
```

and I want to call it in the SpaceTest class:

```
public class SpaceTest extends Space3D {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Space2D point2D = new Space2D();

    // I also have a Space 3D class that inherits from the 2D class.
    // but I want to call the distance method from the Space 2D class so I'll try to do it like this:

    point2D.distance(3,4) // <-- wrong 

   }
}
```

I would like to put 3 and 4 after p1 and p2 from the distance method but I get a bug that I have to put integers in it if I want to do so, so my question what do I have to put in calling this method so that I can run it, i.e. what do I have to put for this object ?? "Space2D p1"?
point2D.distance (???)

Thank you in advance for your help and explanation, I hope you will help me understand this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You want  `distance(3, 4)`, so passing a couple of ints returns the same value as `distance(new Point2D(3,0), new Point2D(4,0))` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
public double distance(Space2D p1, Space2D p2) {
...
```

This means when you invoke `distance` you have to pass in two objects of type `Space2D`.

```
point2D.distance(3,4) <-- wrong
```

You tried to invoke it with two integers, which is why you get the error.  Points have an x and y coordinate, what does it even mean to ask for the distance between 3 and 4 if the domain is R<sup>2</sup>.

What you probably want is something like

```
int dist = point2d.distance(new Point2D(3,0), new Point2D(4,0));
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're putting integers as parameter which is not allowing to take as parameter. Distance function takes  distance(Space2D p1, Space2D p2) Space2D object.

You can use like this:

In Space2D Class :

```
public class Space2D {

    private int x;
    private int y;

    public Space2D(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    //several other methods etc.

    //for example I will take this method

    public static double distance(Space2D p1, Space2D p2) {
        double dx = p1.x - p2.x;
        double dy = p1.y - p2.y;
        return Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
    }
}
```

In SpaceTest class :

```
public class SpaceTest extends Space3D {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Space2D.distance(new Space2D(3, 2), new Space2D(3, 2));

    }
}
```